# Getting undefined method `add_role' with Rails 6, Rolify using UUID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uuid, rolify

I just added rolify to my Rails 6 app, which is using UUID for all tables.

After the initial errors I found that I [need to change my migrations slightly](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/FAQ) to deal with the UUID. I am also using a model named 'Person' instead of the default 'User'.
I have tried restarting my server  (several times) but I still get the following:

```
2.6.2 :002 > p.add_role :admin
```

***Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):2***
***NoMethodError (undefined method `add_role' for #Person::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fe37ec29408>)
2.6.2 :003 >***

Here are the applicable models:

**role.rb**

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :people, :join_table => :people_roles


belongs_to :resource,
           :polymorphic => true,
           :optional => true


validates :resource_type,
          :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
          :allow_nil => true

scopify
end
```

**person.rb**

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
rolify

def full_name
    "#{self.last_name}, #{self.first_name}"
end
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :trackable
end
```

applicable schema:

```
create_table "people", id: :uuid, default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "email", default: "", null: false
t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
t.string "last_name"
t.string "first_name"
t.string "gender"
t.uuid "personable_id"
t.string "personable_type"
t.string "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"
t.inet "last_sign_in_ip"
t.integer "failed_attempts", default: 10, null: false
t.string "unlock_token"
t.datetime "locked_at"
t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.string "type"
t.index ["email"], name: "index_people_on_email", unique: true
t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_people_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
t.index ["unlock_token"], name: "index_people_on_unlock_token", unique: true
 end

create_table "people_roles", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.uuid "person_id"
    t.uuid "role_id"
    t.index ["person_id", "role_id"], name: "index_people_roles_on_person_id_and_role_id"
  end

create_table "roles", id: :uuid, default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.uuid "resource_id"
    t.string "resource_type"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["name", "resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_roles_on_name_and_resource_type_and_resource_id"
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_roles_on_name"
  end
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `p` is not a `Person` but a collection of `Person` objects as indicated by `ActiveRecord_Relation`.

If you would like all of those people to have the admin role then it would be

```
p.each {|person| person.add_role :admin }
```

Otherwise you will need to change the code that populates `p` to return a single `Person` object. For instance if you are populating `p` as

```
p = Person.where(uuid: some_uuid)
```

Then change this to

```
p = Person.find_by(uuid: some_uuid) # or Person.find_by_uuid(some_uuid)
```

`find_by` will return an instance of the class (or `nil` none are found) by selecting the first record where the condition is true. Since `uuid` by virtue is unique this should not be an issue.

Comment: Amazing! Of course. I did a Person.where... to populate p. Thank you!